# Why readfile() is acting strange in reading a php file but working fine on text file

Tags: php

Code in index.php

```
<?php
echo readfile('hello.php');
?>
```

code in hello.php

```
<?php 
echo "hello this is a php file";
?>
```

The output I'm getting is `47` but when I add a line before the string in hello.php i.e 
`echo "<br/> hello this is a php file";`   I'm getting output `hello this is a php file"; ?>52`

And when removing the closing php tag in hello.php output in index.php is

```
hello this is a php file"; 50
```

But there is no such behavior reading from a text file.
Why output of index.php being three different ways in case of reading a php file?

Comment: [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) echos to the screen for you and then returns the number of bytes that it read (that's what the `47` is).  Also, check the source of your page, your browser is probably trying to read `<?php` as an HTML tag.

Comment: @RocketHazmat worthy of an answer.

Comment: you can use the file_get_contents() if you want to read the file as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) echos to the screen for you.  `echo readfile()` is unnecessary.  After echoing, `readfile` returns the number of bytes that it read, so that's where the `47` is coming from.

You can just do:

```
readfile('hello.php');
```

or you can use

```
echo file_get_contents('hello.php');
```

if you choose.

Also, I suggest you check the source of your page in your browser (consult your browser's docs).  Chances are, you'll see the PHP file clearly there.  Your browser is probably trying to render the response as an HTML file.  It's trying to parse `<?php` as an HTML tag.  That's why it's not displayed.

To get around this, you can try to add

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

before you echo your hello.php file to the screen.  This should tell the browser that it's receiving just a text file and not to try to parse it as HTML.

Comment: I know where the number is comming from and If i don't use echo in index file nothing gonna display, not even the number of bytes

Comment: @user1906399: Have checked the "page source" in your browser?

Comment: yes page source is displaying as expected, but why the browser not showing anything when i don't put a <br/>before the string of hello.php file?

Comment: @user1906399: Because it's trying to interpret `<?php` as an HTML tag.  Try to add `header('Content-type: text/plain');` before you echo the file.  That should tell the browser to just display the file and not try to parse it as HTML.

Comment: but that's  not what i'm trying to achieve, if i set the header as plain text php tags will also be displayed, i want to display the output of the hello.php which is just "hello this is a php file" and nothing else.

Comment: @user1906399: OH!  You didn't specify that anywhere.  I didn't know that was what you wanted.  In that case `readfile` is the *wrong* tool.  You want `include 'hello.php';`.

Comment: ok, so i can't display output of a php file using file functions like file(), readfile(), file_get_contents() or fopen? so is this mean file functions are only used for text files?

Comment: @user1906399: Yep, exactly  :-)  Well, they aren't just for text files, you can use them with binary files too.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior for php file is same as other files. If you go to page source you will see the `<?php` tag is also present.

[image]