# PHP: Readfile command seems to produce some unwanted numbers

Tags: php

My PHP code on the server is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo readfile("mytext.txt");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the content of "mytext.txt" is the following:

> Can you see me?
>   I am here!

However, what I get in the browser is this:

> Can you see me? I am here!27

Where did this number 27 come from?!

Comment: its giving the length of the string in your file

Comment: why not `echo file_get_contents('mytext.txt');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove echo as it is output the stream, removing echo will out put the file text try it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
readfile("mytext.txt");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860475/6786476).

Basically, `readfile` already outputs the stream, so adding an `echo` in front of it is not necessary.